# Apagar arquivos dentro da pasta

Tags: vb.net

**Apagar arquivos dentro da pasta**

Bom eu tava criando um software onde ele apaga os arquivos da pasta exemplo

Criei uma pasta Oi ai quando abre outro software ele fica mandando logs para essa pasta

Então eu queria criar um aplicativo onde ele apaga os arquivos dentro dessa pasta menos a pasta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   'Caminho da sua pasta 
    Dim pasta As String = "C:\...\Desktop\Nova pasta"

    'Pega todos os arquivos dentro dela 
    For Each arquivo In FileIO.FileSystem.GetFiles(pasta, FileIO.SearchOption.SearchTopLevelOnly)
        'Apaga
        System.IO.File.Delete(arquivo)
    Next
```

Comment: Obrigado deu certo aqui

Comment: Mano Estou com uma duvida coloquei a pasta onde ele exclui só que varia entre os usuários então meu usuario e Administrador mais no computador do meu amigo o usuario dele e Zeus como eu faço para colocar para que em qualquer pc rode e apague os arquivos ?

Comment: Você pode usar uma pasta padrão do Windows como a %appdata%:  Dim appData As String = GetFolderPath(SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)